# Azure App Service breaking on every restart

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

On every release to the app service or any restart of the app service, I get 502 error.

If I then modify a couple of the connectionStrings in the appsettings.json file the app starts working again.  When I say modify, I just changed the `initial catalog` from the demo DB to the dev DB and then back to the demo DB, the 502 error was solved.

**1st question** has anybody seen this type issue where the app service breaks until the appsettings.json file is modified?

**2nd question** this is probably related to the 1st issue.  I have a connection string that points to the DEMO Db but writes to the DEV Db.  Could there be corruption or something that relates to both of these issues?

Extra information, this is aspnetcore 2.1 app.  the connections strings point to SQL Server.

Comment: Are you using Azure SQL Database ? or OnPrem SQL Server ?

Comment: Both Demo and Dev Db are SQL Server, not azure sql.  They both sit on the same  SQL Server instance.

Comment: Have you specified the connection strings in the App Settings of the App Service?

Comment: I had originally, but I deleted early in the process of testing the problem.